# Connect the DAX to lambda function in aws VPC

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Unable to connect the call the DAX api from lamda function getting error while connecting.

```
TART RequestId: 91744a72-6b81-11e7-b7b9-81ab3e1f67f1 Version: $LATEST
[2017-07-18 06:23:09.356] NO-REQUEST-ID ERROR c.a.d.c.SocketTubePool - error connecting to /172.31.20.237:8111 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[2017-07-18 06:23:09.356] NO-REQUEST-ID ERROR c.a.d.c.SocketTubePool - error connecting to /172.31.20.237:8111 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[2017-07-18 06:23:09.364] NO-REQUEST-ID ERROR c.a.d.c.SocketTubePool - error connecting to /172.31.20.237:8111 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[2017-07-18 06:23:09.364] NO-REQUEST-ID ERROR c.a.d.c.c.Cluster - caught exception during cluster refresh: java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts: [dax122.fwef.clusefwefwetercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111]
java.io.IOException: failed to configure cluster endpoints from hosts: [dax122.fwef.clusefwefwetercfg.dax.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:8111]
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you check the security group configuration on the security group used to launch the DAX cluster? You will need to authorize inbound traffic on TCP port 8111 on the security group used to launch the cluster, using the security group used for the lambda function configuration as the source. Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.create-cluster.cli.configure-inbound-rules.html) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

This is connection time out Exception. you should check AWS firewall settings if port 8111 is open in inbound rules.

These settings are on AWS dashboard in security policy section.